# Is it possible to get an &str out of a RefCell<string>

Tags: rust, refcell

Trying to un-XY this problem as much as possible

I have a struct like this

```
struct Thing {
     text:String
     other : Other
}
```

and a method signature like this

```
impl Thing {
   fn get_text(&self) -> &str{

   }
}
```

Note that get_text is immutable.  ( I cant make it mutable. I am am dropping a replacement implementation of a componenet into a large project, I cannot change the signatures)

`Other` has a method `get_text` too. It returns `&[String]`. I need to convert that slice into a '\n' delimited `String` and return a `&str` pointing at it.

This works in a mutable environment;

```
fn get_text(&mut self) -> {
    self.msg = self.other.get_text().join("\n");
    &self.msg 
}
```

But it has to be immutable.

So I tried to use RefCell.

```
struct Thing {
     text:RefCell<String>,
     other : Other
}  

pub fn get_text(&self) -> Ref<String> {
    let text = self.other.get_text().join("/n");
    self.text.replace(text);
    self.text.borrow()
}
```

I can almost get it to work. Depending on how the caller uses that return value, sometimes the DeRef trait kicks in and sometimes not. But I also get complicated borrow errors in the calling code eg (this is caller's code, `self.input` is an instance of `Thing`)

```
fn foo(&mut self) {
    let msg = self.input.get_text();
    let signed_msg = self.bar(&msg);
    if let std::result::Result::Ok(signed_msg) = signed_msg {
        self.input.set_text(signed_msg);
    }
}
```

produces this

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `self.input` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
   --> src\components\commit.rs:352:4
    |
349 |         let msg = self.input.get_text();
    |                   ---------- immutable borrow occurs here
...
352 |             self.input.set_text(signed_msg);
    |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
353 |         }
354 |     }
    |     - immutable borrow might be used here, when `msg` is dropped and runs the destructor for type `Ref<'_, std::string::String>`
```

note that this

```
let signed_msg = self.bar(&msg);
                          ^
```

is an edit I already did just to see what I can get working. I really would prefer not to make any changes to the calling code

I feel that I should be able to return a &str somehow, rather than a Ref. The lifetime of self.msg is guaranteed to be OK, I mean in a mutable env I could simply return &self.msg. My caller is not expecting anything mutable to be returned, they are just reading, but I dont see a RefCell method that returns a &T. Maybe I should use something else.

EDIT

I found that I can make this work

```
struct Thing {
     text:OnceCell<String>,
     other : Other
}  


pub fn get_text(&self) -> &str {
    let text = self.other.get_text().join("/n");
    self.msg.get_or_init(|| text).as_str()
}
```

But That only works if get_text is only called once (which I cannot be sure of). Feel I am getting very close

EDIT 2

Since I own all the code paths that lead to `other` updating its internal state I can call `msg.take` in those paths (they are all &mut self functions). So any update erases the `msg:OnceCell` and the next call to get_text will rebuild it. Perfect

Comment: You can't return a `&T` with a `RefCell` because the guard (`Ref`) maintains the reference count. That is, the `Drop` implementation for `Ref` adjusts the reference count in the `RefCell` so that future calls to one of the `borrow` methods will work correctly. A plain reference is not able to do this. I can't think of a way you could solve this given your constraints without leaking a string, other than precomputing the string before `get_text` gets called.

Comment: If you don't want to return `Ref<'_, T>` for better encapsulation, you can return `impl Deref<Target = T> + '_` instead.

Comment: @cdhowie well I just worked out that I can make it work using OnceCell, if I know that get_text is only called once, since Oncell::get_or_init returns &T. I feel I am getting close. See edit in the question

Comment: The fundamental issue is that someone could call this twice and obtain two references. You can't mutate it even behind any kind of UnsafeCell since there's a reference out there. Besides leaking, you could also make a new string every time and store them in a Vec that only gets dropped when the whole Thing gets dropped, which definitely happens when there are no references left.

Comment: @cafce25 that question is different since they are okay with returning a guard.

Comment: Well if this question doesn't get reopened, here's my solution. Miri is okay with it. Note that if you're keeping `Thing` around for the entire program, this is slightly worse for memory usage than leaking. You want `Thing` to live as briefly as possible. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ea21589fc56f8a477ae974ff311ad3de You could also make a method that takes `&mut self` and use that to clear `Thing` in addition to the drop, since such a method wouldn't be callable while `&str` refs exist.

Comment: @pm100 You're not getting close to returning `&T`, that can ever be sound. If it were, what's to stop you from calling `foo.get_text()`, and then mutating `foo.text`? That would make the existing reference dangle. If it's unacceptable to modify the signature of `get_text()`, the only remaining alternative is leaking memory. If you can modify the signature (and callers) of `get_text()`, there are ways to make it nice to use even without exposing `Ref<...>`.

Comment: @cafce25 it's not the right answer to the question, though. I think this question could be made original with a better title.

Comment: I don't think you can do that without changing the caller code in some way.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman shame this q got closed, I would like to answer it myself. Anyway I got it working by using oncecell (as shown in edit to q). Since I own all the code paths that could update the result of other.get_text I placed a text.take there. This makes the get_or_init reload the data. Done

Comment: @pm100 I'd like to see the code that does that (`text.take`) because that doesn't sound like it should work given that you have `&self` not `&mut self`.

Comment: @cdhowie - the paths that update the state of what other.get_text returns are all &mut self, they are known by the caller to be things that update Things state. The read text is the immutable call (since, as its name suggests, its reading)

Comment: @pm100 Ah. I mean that's basically what I suggested in my first comment. You don't even need a cell or interior mutability in that case, just have a `String`.

Comment: @cdhowie - it too expensive for me to update the String on every update (it happens a lot, and synchronusly with the end user). This way I recreate that text string whenever it has changed *and* the user asks for it